# How to change file and directory names with find?

Tags: linux, bash

I changed project name and now I have many files an directories with old name. How to replace these names with find?

```
find . -name "*old_name*" -exec ???
```

Comment: make a backup before you start

Comment: why find? Have a look at `replace`

Comment: what does your directory hierarchy look like? Are the affected directory names all on one level?

Comment: Consider doing the backup with `git`. It's much easier tracking your changes and whether your changes are correct that way.

Answer (score 2):

This `find` should work for you:

```
find . -name "old_name" -execdir mv "{}" new_name +
```

This will find files with the name `old_name` from the current dir in all sub directories and rename them to `new_name`.

Comment: I think this is a bad solution: if he has `./foo/bar/old_name`, that will try to execute `mv ./foo/bar/old_name new_name` instead of, what is probably wanted, `cd ./foo/bar && mv old_name new_name`

Comment: and at you both - how would you cd into a dynamic folder? maybe exec is not the best way forth but to use a for loop and then strip folder etc

Comment: I think that `dirname` is not a builtin in bash. Would it not be more performance to use parameter expansion and use `dir="${1%/*}"` instead? (Or just put it on the `mv` line and skip the extra variable.) Are there cases where this would fail?

Comment: Thanks. After your comment I realized this can be simplified further. (edited)

Answer (score 1):

Below is what I have used in the past.  The biggest gotcha is the RHEL rename (c) vs Debian rename (perl) - They take different options.  The example below uses RHEL c based rename command.  Remove the '-type f' to also rename the directories.

```
find . -type f -name "*old_name*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} /usr/bin/rename "old_name" "new_name" {}
```

Comment: If renaming directories, I'm guessing the "find" should use "-depth", just to be safe (depth-first processing).

Answer (score 0):

```
newname="myfile.sh"; for files in $(find Doc2/scripts/ -name gw_watch_err.sh); do echo $files; dir=${files%/*}; cfile=${files##*/}; echo "$dir -- $cfile";  echo "mv $cfile $newname";  done
Doc2/scripts/gateway/gw_watch_err.sh
Doc2/scripts/gateway -- gw_watch_err.sh
mv gw_watch_err.sh myfile.sh
```

you could also add:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname file
```

where maxdepth will ensure you dont need to worry about sub folders and iname means case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my solution:

```
find . -name "*old_name*" -exec rename 's/old_name/new_name/g' {} \;
```

But this works for directories which name not contain "old_name", otherwise find say for example:

```
find: `./old_name': No such file or directory
```

Because it trying search in "old_name" directory, and the directory is already a "new_name"

Answer (score 0):

## renaming multiple directories with `find`: how to catch the catches

### here's a little story on how to rename multiple files with `find`, but for the impatient I first put the proper command for your specific problem here:

```
find -depth -name "old name" -execdir mv -iv {} "new name" \;
```

### and for the patient ones, a few misadventures with `find`, restricting changes to directories only:

- we want to rename all directories named `old dir` into `new dir` recursively inside a current directory

  - we create an empty directory inside which we create a simple directory hierarchy:

    ```sh
    $ cd $(mktemp -d) && mkdir -p "old dir" "subdir/old dir/old dir"
    $ find | sort
    .
    ./old dir
    ./subdir
    ./subdir/old dir
    ./subdir/old dir/old dir
    ```
  - the use of of the `-exec` action works only for a rename directly under a current directory, which you can see by dry-running a rename command (**note that** the shell doesn't output the quotes, which is not an error):

    ```sh
    $ find -type d -name "old dir" -exec echo mv -iv {} "new dir" \;
    mv -iv ./subdir/old dir new dir
    mv -iv ./subdir/old dir/old dir new dir
    mv -iv ./old dir new dir
    ```

    **note that** only the first rename command would work as expected
  - the use of the `-execdir` action runs the command from the subdirectory containing the matched directory:

    ```sh
    $ find -type d -name "old dir" -execdir echo mv -iv {} "new dir" \;
    mv -iv ./old dir new dir
    mv -iv ./old dir new dir
    mv -iv ./old dir new dir
    ```

    which seems fine as the rename commands are run in the matching directories, so we no longer dry-run:

    ```sh
    $ find -type d -name "old dir" -execdir mv -iv {} "new dir" \;
    './old dir' -> 'new dir'
    find: ‘./subdir/old dir’: No such file or directory
    './old dir' -> 'new dir'
    find: ‘./old dir’: No such file or directory
    $ find | sort
    .
    ./new dir
    ./subdir
    ./subdir/new dir
    ./subdir/new dir/old dir
    ```

    the problem is that the `old dir` is renamed `new dir` and `find` cannot descend further inside a renamed directory
  - a solution is to ***process each directory's contents before the directory itself***, which is precisely what the `-depth` option does:

    ```sh
    $ cd $(mktemp -d) && mkdir -p "old dir" "subdir/old dir/old dir"
    $ find -depth -type d -name "old dir" -execdir mv -iv {} "new dir" \;
    './old dir' -> 'new dir'
    './old dir' -> 'new dir'
    './old dir' -> 'new dir'
    $ find | sort
    .
    ./new dir
    ./subdir
    ./subdir/new dir
    ./subdir/new dir/new dir
    ```

Answer (score -1):

## 1. First, backup your directories and files

The following [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) code run on my OS X and Ubuntu boxes.

## 2. Rename the directories from ***old_dir*** to ***new_dir***:

```
for d in $(find . -maxdepath X -type d -name 'old_dir'); do mv $d "$(dirname $d)/new_dir"; done
```

***X*** is a number used to specify the depth of replacing ***old_dir***

## 3. Rename the files from ***old_file*** to ***new_file***:

```
for f in $(find . -type f -name 'old_file'); do mv $f "$(dirname $f)/new_file"; done
```

4. Don't care about @[Benjamin W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w) and @[ghoti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072112/ghoti) them one for his ***ForMatted code*** and @ghoti try to orient the question to his Pitfalls.

Hi, @[Benjamin W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w) what about this new post? and @[ghoti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072112/ghoti) did you run the above code incorrectly on your machine? If the code can't work just let me know or post a question pls, and if you had a better one pls post here let we know.

Comment: Your recommendation is [number one on the Bash Pitfalls list](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Also, always quote your variables.

Comment: @Benjamin W. Did you try the my answer is wrong or correct? Did you know question needs a answer or needs a correct formatted but wrong answer just like you change the 'backup' to 'Backup'. I know you try to find the correct formatted text not the answer, and you did a good job and Job.

Comment: @Benjamin W. I'd answer the old question because I'd the same one and I find a solution and want some people can know it and not the It. :)

Comment: I didn't try the answer, but as @ghoti points out, there is probably a better way to do it. As for my edit, I just tried to improve readability with the list and code formatting. For capitalization, I capitalized beginnings of proper sentences, like the first and third point on the list, but not the second one, which looks like a continuation of the first one. If you don't like an edit, you can always [edit] your answer yourself, or roll back my edits. I do think my edit is an improvement, though ;) And just to be clear, I didn't vote on your answer.

Comment: Hi, @ghoti The better way for bash is you to redesign the bash. Here at stackoverflow I want to resolve the question or find the answer.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yeah, you did your Job :) Now let the bash's specialist ghoti to answer all questions follow the [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) or let him redesign the bash.

Comment: I think you're a little too dismissive of the criticism. Did you read the link @ghoti posted? It's a good read.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I'd read, what about you? HERE we need answer or answer the question, not about some pitfalls, for everyone We can't write always CORRECT code on any environment, we are not the Bash Syntax Lawyer. We just meet some problems so we are here, what do you think about this? If I'd some bash syntax problem I'll paid for Bash Syntax Lawyer ghoti .

Comment: Of course, you can provide a one-off answer that solves exactly the problem at hand; a portable, stable solution that might be helpful for more people than just the person asking might get more recognition in the form of upvotes.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Sounds like good. up-votes or down-votes is not the reason for I'm here and for We are here.